# How to write addressToLocations onError?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geocoding

How can I write a code for checking the error condition in Javascript (ArcGIS) for
addressToLocations(params, callback?, errback?).

if somebody entered an invalid address- how can I call error function?
Please share your thoughts!

my code below:-

-->

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<title>Find Address</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.2/js/esri/css/esri.css" />



<script type="text/javascript">
  var djConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true
  };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("esri.tasks.locator");
  dojo.require("dojo.number");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
  dojo.require("dijit.form.Textarea");



  var map, locator;

  function init() {
    locator = new esri.tasks.Locator("http://arc-gis-1/ArcGIS/rest/services/Essential/AddressLoc/GeocodeServer");
    dojo.connect(locator, "onAddressToLocationsComplete", showResults);

  }
  function clearContents(element) {
    element.value = '';
    }

  function locate() {
    dojo.empty("messages");
    dojo.empty("content");
    dojo.empty("candScore");
    var address = {"Single Line Input":dojo.byId("address").value};
    var options = {
      address:address,
      outFields:["Loc_name"]
    }
    locator.addressToLocations(options);
  }

  function showResults(candidates) {
    var candidate;
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
    var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Location", "Address: ${address}<br />Score: ${score}<br />Source locator: ${locatorName}");
    symbol.setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE);
    symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([153,0,51,0.75]));
    var geom;
   // alert(candidates[0].score);
    if (candidates.attribute==undefined)
    {
        var content = "That doesn't seem to be a valid address! ";
        dojo.byId('content').innerHTML = content;
    }

    dojo.every(candidates,function(candidate){
    alert(candidate.score);
      //console.log(candidate.score);
      var candScore= "Score =" + candidate.score;

      if (candidate.score > 80) {
        console.log(candidate.location);
        var attributes = { address: candidate.Match_addr, score:candidate.score, locatorName:candidate.attributes.Loc_name };   
        geom = candidate.location;
        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(geom, symbol, attributes, infoTemplate);
        var queryTaskTouches = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://arc-gis-1/ArcGIS/rest/services/Apps/Sheriff_ESN/MapServer/0");
        var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = ["*"];
        query.geometry = graphic.geometry;
        query.spatialRelationship = esri.tasks.Query.SPATIAL_REL_WITHIN;
        queryTaskTouches.execute(query);
        dojo.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<b>Executing Polygon Touches Query...</b>";

  dojo.connect(queryTaskTouches, "onComplete", function(fset) {

      var resultFeatures = fset.features;
      for (var i=0, il=resultFeatures.length; i<il; i++) {
        var querygraphic = resultFeatures[i];
        querygraphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        querygraphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);

      }
      var matchAdd = candidate.address;
      var ESN= querygraphic.attributes.ESNs;

   content = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Address</th><th>ESN</th></tr>"
                    +"<tr><td>"+  matchAdd +"</td><td>"+  ESN +"</td></tr>"
           "</table>";
      dojo.byId('messages').innerHTML = "";
      dojo.byId('content').innerHTML = content;
      dojo.byId('candScore').innerHTML = candScore;
    });



      }
      else
      {
      matchAdd="Not a Valid Address";
      var ESN= " ";
      var content = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Address</th><th>ESN</th></tr>"
                    +"<tr><td>"+  matchAdd +"</td><td>"+  ESN +"</td></tr>"
           "</table>";
      dojo.byId('messages').innerHTML = "";
      dojo.byId('content').innerHTML = content;
      }



    });

  }

  dojo.addOnLoad(init);
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks. I am enclosing my code. Please see the "If statement" where I was trying to check "undefined". I am seeing that locator has a way of checking onError/errback?. But, I am not sure how to implement it:(

Answer (score 2):

Just change your:

```
locator.addressToLocations(options);
```

to:

```
locator.addressToLocations(options,cBack,errBack);
```

The cBack, would actually be the same as the showResults call at:

```
  dojo.connect(locator, "onAddressToLocationsComplete", showResults);
```

The errBack, is what you are looking for! If there will be an error during the "addressToLocations", this method will be called. You can then process the error within this function:

```
function errBack(error){
    console.log("Error - "+error)
    console.log("Error code - "+error.code)
}
```